# MySql not displaying all columns in the result

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to teach myself DBA. when I execute this query:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN Trans_type LIKE '%C%' 
             THEN 'Credit Card' 
             ELSE NULL 
          END AS type 
FROM Transactions 
WHERE cust_no=2 && Trans_type LIKE '%C%';
```

I get the following:

```
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+
| cust_no | date       | Category          | Subcategory          | Amount | Trans_Type | type        |
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+
         | Credit Card | Bills & Utilities | Bills & Utilities Ot | 5      | C
         | Credit Card | Household/Home    | DIY/Home Improvement | 15     | C
         | Credit Card | Shopping          | Clothing & Accessori | 215    | C
         | Credit Card | Shopping          | Clothing & Accessori | 135    | C
+---------+------------+-------------------+----------------------+--------+------------+-------------+

4 rows in set (3.53 sec)
```

Why are the cust_no, date not displaying and also the CASE type displaying at the start in my mysql console?

Thanks.

The Table Transactions Description below:

`+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| cust_no     | varchar(10) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| date        | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Category    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Subcategory | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Amount      | varchar(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Trans_Type  | varchar(5)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

Comment: You'll need to provide the DDL for the table you're selecting from and sample data.

Comment: Which tool are you using to get these results? (The MySQL Command-Line Tool, MySQL WorkBench, another tool?)

Comment: something is not right..Credit Card in date..is it formatting issue ? Please provide us with some sample input and `create table` schema.

Comment: i am using mysql command-line tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of looks like there's a CR (carriage return, ASCII 13) after the C in `Trans_Type`. Try specifying the column names, and put that first; it would disappear, but the other columns would be visible.

You can explicitly check for non-printing characters like this using the ORD() function. Let's say `Trans_Type` is a `CHAR(3)` (or `NCHAR(3)`):

```
SELECT ORD(SUBSTR(TransType,1,1)) as FirstChar
      ,ORD(SUBSTR(TransType,2,1)) as SecondChar
      ,ORD(SUBSTR(TransType,3,1)) as ThirdChar
  FROM Transactions 
 WHERE cust_no=2 && Trans_type LIKE '%C%';
```

would show you the character codes for each character; check the appropriate code page to see what the characters actually are (as noted, for ASCII, a 13 represents a carriage return, which would move the cursor to the start of the current line in Windows at least).

If this is the problem, you should be able to use `REPLACE(Trans_Type, @BadChar, '')` to remove the offending character from your results. For ASCII and the carriage return character, `@BadChar` would actually be `CHAR(13 using ascii)`. So, your query would be:

```
SELECT `cust_no`, `date`, `Category`, `Subcategory`, `Amount`
      ,REPLACE(Trans_Type, CHAR(13 USING ascii), '') as Trans_Type
      ,CASE WHEN Trans_type LIKE '%C%' 
         THEN 'Credit Card' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS type 
  FROM Transactions 
 WHERE cust_no=2 && Trans_type LIKE '%C%';
```

Note: mostly untested, as I don't have your data.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was a carriage return problem. your solution fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a display bug in the mysql command line interface. If you run the same query in another client (such as MySQL Workbench), you will see all your results. To demonstrate this in the MySQL command-line, add some text in the first column to "pad" the second column display. Ex: Select "First Name is    -->", first_name, last_name from names_view; QED